# Contact Names showing up on Google Search even when they are not public

Tags: drupal, contacts, drupal-views

All of our contact first name & last name are appearing visible on our site even when they have requested not to be. It is pulling their contact id and putting it into a public directory drupal view. We have an opt-in public directory that shows certain fields when the radio button is "Yes". We've been able to hide the email address, etc. but the name should not even appear unless we give it permission. Anyone else has this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will probably need to paste some screenshots of your view and/or do an export of the view and paste somewhere so folk can take a look

Comment: Hi, try accessing the view page not logged in (anonymous window). If you do see the names, the problem is on how you built your view and it doesn't properly exclude the right contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at this.  The pages that listed individuals' names were pulling the Display Name for the page title via `civicrm_entity`.  So even when though the filtering was working correctly to not display the View, the name would still come through.  It was corrected by giving a generic title and moving the name into the View.

Answer (score 0):

Oh shoot - it sounds like your View is not properly filtering out the "not Yes" radio value.

1. Check your View carefully -> especially the Filter section
2. Post your View here (screenshot -> not of the data -> but the Views config screen itself)
3. Look for and at other Pages/Blocks generated by your View [if there are more than one -> it's possible that Google has indexed Contact Names on that page View only]

Comment: It does also look like indexing to me but am not completely convinced its the solution. The filters are on correctly.

Comment: It has to be a filter issue - I can't see how it's not;