# Anonymous users can't View details of a Contact in a public directory Listing

Tags: wordpress, profile, permissions, directory

Currently on CiviCRM 5.1.2 / WordPress 4.9.6 in my dev site and on my Live site on CiviCRM 5.0.2 / WordPress 4.9.6.  The reason for the CiviCRM difference was it was my last attempt to see the cause of a behavior I'm seeing:

**Problem:**  *Anonymous users are not able to View the details of a contact that is in our public directory listing.*
**Scenarios:**

- *When an anonymous user clicks 'View' they are redirected to the home page.*
- *For ANY logged in user it will show the details of the contact selected.*

**Expectation:**  We are wanting even anonymous users to be able to see the details of the directory.

---

**Things that have been checked:**

1. I have looked for any errors during the timeframe in the Log files located in:

> wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog

and

> ../wp-content/error.log

2. Checked the permission of the Profile that is being used for the directory Listing and detail View.

   - ***Used For*** option has    ***Standalone Form or Directory***  and ***Search Views*** checked
   - The group, ***Hub Directory of Organizations***, is selected as the Limit listing group.
   - ***No account creation option***,  ***Issue warning and do not save selected***, ***No Proximity*** search and ***Enable mapping for
     this profile*** is selected
   - All fields are set to either ***Expose Publicly*** or ***Expose Publicly and for Listings***
   - As one test I had all fields set to ***View Only*** to no avail
3. Changed the permission on the limit listing group, ***Hub Directory of Organizations***, and its parent group from ***User and User Admin Only*** to ***Expose Publicly*** to see if it made a difference.  No avail.
4. Checked WordPress / CiviCRM permission access to make sure the following were checked:  ***Access_all_custom_data***, ***access_contact_reference_fields***, ***access_uploaded_files***, ***profile_listings***, ***profile_listings_and_forms*** and ***profile_view***.  At one point I tried ***view_all_contacts***, but to no avail.
5. Disabled any new extensions and the one that wrote for special formatting of my directory to see if it was affecting the permissions or access.  Did not fix.

What else should I check for?  A combination of things to be checked together?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to expose contacts to anonymous users.

The only place where this is possible is with registered participants for an event because you could create a public participant listing.

The other way to expose data to anonymous users to use a module from your CMS. In Drupal you could use the views module, and in Wordpress you can show a profile list on a wordpress page.

Comment: Not necessarily true...Example: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7577/front-end-profile-view-issues  and even the worst example if you don't want it to happen: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20543/contact-names-showing-up-on-google-search-even-when-they-are-not-public

Comment: You are right but toth are using functionality from their cms, which is the Drupal Views module, or profile listing on a word press page.